# Exporting shapefile to KML with labels

Tags: qgis, shapefile, labeling, kml

In QGIS, When exporting my point shapefile to KML, points label are not visible in Google Earth Pro. I follow these steps:

1. In QGIS, my point shapefile has a name attribute
2. Right click on the shape file, go to export, format=kml and select all in the select fields to export
3. When loading this KML in Google Earth, name of my points won't show up. If I select a point, the attribute window shows the name data is there and I can name each point manually but this is too time consuming.

Does anybody know the trick to get labels displayed right away?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the issue, but when exporting to KML make sure to write the field name that represent the labels in the NameField as you can see below.

[image]

Here is the result

[image]

If you write another field name, it will be loaded automatically into GoogleEarth

[image]

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: @ahmadhand This is exactly what I was looking for and it works. Thank you

Comment: @OlivierCristol You are welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted so that it can help others.