# Exporting Shapefile as KML with polygons and labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, kml

The link [Previous answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333972/exporting-shapefile-to-kml-with-labels) does not work with this file.  As the file I was exporting was a clipped file I tried using the original file but with same result, polygons but no labels.  It is a public access Welsh government file made by a Program called Forester, could file be corrupt?  It displays correctly as Shapefile.
I have tried the answer linked to 4 times with the result of a KML with polygons and no name attached. If exported within QGIS as Shapefile initialy there are polygons, no names but if I untick and retick PRISPECIES the names are displayed. Will keep trying I need an answer to the problem.  In GEP KML I can click on a polygon, the pop up displays all the attributes from original file including PRISPECIES.  Still trying by saving as different file types.  When saved as KML with layer added to QGIS the QGIS layer does not display name but Properties - Label Value = prispecies the name is displayed.  When exporting to KML I follow instructions in suggested "Correct answer".

Comment: please edit your original question to make clear exactly what you are trying to do and what is not working (after you have tried the answer you link to).

Comment: I have tried the answer linked to 4 times with the result of a KML with polygons and no name attached.  If exported as Shapefile initialy there are polygons, no names  but if I untick and retick PRISPECIES the names are displayed.  Will keep trying I need an answer to the problem.

Comment: Please add that information to your original question